# How to use a FeatureCollection (imported from GEOJson format) and filter a ImageCollection?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I have a FeatureCollection imported from a GEOJson file (it was extracted from a shapefile) and import it to use with Google Earth Engine API in Python.

The problem is I can't figure out how to use it with ImageCollection's filterBounds function. I'have tried several ways and can't get the desired result (mostly error responses)

I would also need (if possible) to find a way to crop those images so the result has the initial shape I'm using (a river in that case)

```py
import ee
import json
import geojson
from IPython.display import Image

ee.Initialize()

# GEOJson (extracted from shapefile)
with open("/content/drive/My Drive/.../mascara.json") as json_file:
   gjson = geojson.load(json_file)

# FeatureCollection imported from geojson
fc = ee.FeatureCollection(geojson.dumps(gjson))

# Landsat Collection (focus on filterBounds function)
imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filterBounds(fc).filterDate('2016-12-01','2016-12-31')

# trying to filter image by FeatureCollection (not working at all)
image = ee.Image(imageCollection.sort('CLOUD_COVER').first())
Image(url=image.select(['B5','B4','B3']).getThumbUrl({'min':0,'max':3000}))
```

Some error response I've received:

```py
EEException: Collection.loadTable: Collection asset '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":...
```

I've just started learning the Google Earth Engine's API but can't get the filtered image and river shape I need.

Comment: post the question on gis stackoverflow community

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('shape/_json/roi.json') as f:
        txt = f.read()
        f.close()

temp = json.JSONDecoder().decode(txt)
temp = temp['features'][0]['geometry']

def byteify(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {byteify(key): byteify(value) for key, value in input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [byteify(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input

roi = str(byteify(temp))

roi = roi.replace('\'','\"')
```

Comment: Please, comment your solution to be simpler to understand.